# How can I make the label button became input field instead?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I'm trying to replicate this type of button... So what the developer did here is make the input dynamic, it will be a `type=radio` or `type=checkbox`.

[image]

```
{getCurrentQuestionType === 'single' ? (
<input type='radio' id='choice' name="choice" onChange={handleChange}  value=

{choice.question_choices} />)
: 
(<input type='checkbox' id='choice' name='choice' onChange={handleChange} value={choice.question_choices} style={{display:'none'}}/>

)}

   <label htmlFor='choice' style={{display:'inline-block', backgroundColor: '#ccc', padding: '10px 20px', cursor:'pointer'}}>{choice.question_choices}
    </label>
```

But the problem I encounter here is I can't run the `onChange` anymore since the input became `display:'none'`

How can I make the input disappear but still clickable and can still hold a value?

EDIT:

so what I want here is to create a button but using `input` and `label`, Furthermore, I want to hide the `radio button` or the `checkbox` and make the label button the `radio` or `checkbox` instead, like on the image

Comment: I couldn't understand your issue, can you elaborate ?

Comment: How would it be possible to click on the input if it disappears?

Comment: that is what I'm trying to re-create if possible, instead of showing the circle and the box, make the label instead.

Comment: Anything set to `display: none` cannot be interacted with. Rather than swapping out the entire `<input />` element, I'd explore switching `type=''` attribute _within_ the element per ternary operation.

Comment: Don't use display none!  Use this [technique](https://www.a11ymatters.com/pattern/checkbox/#custom-checkbox-design) to hide the input.  Also, be sure that you're not using the same id more than once on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying concept to this is to really just style based on the `:checked` state of the input. Then using `+`, you can style whatever comes after that input. You can hide the input from sight, leaving you the element that comes after.

You can adapt this in JSX. Leave both inputs in there, just update their state to be in sync with your app's state. Let CSS do the rest.

```css
/* Hide the input element from view */
.toggle-button__state {
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Style the span after the input like a button */
.toggle-button__text {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* When the input is selected, style the span as selected */
.toggle-button__state:checked + .toggle-button__text  {
  background-color: #CCF
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="toggle-button">
    <input class="toggle-button__state" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
    <span class="toggle-button__text">Male</span>
  </label>
  <label class="toggle-button">
    <input class="toggle-button__state" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
    <span class="toggle-button__text">Female</span>
  </label>
</form>
```